# Is this possible to achieve with a particle system?

Tags: particles, physics, shader-nodes

I've seen this used as a tablet background and really like it. I would like to model a few meshes and have them filled with small objects like you see below to achieve the same result.  I'm wondering what would be the best approach - could a particle system be used for this or should I maybe focus or something else?

[image]

Comment: Particle or geometry nodes I would say

Comment: Sculpt the shapes and fill by Particles seems to be a way (with [GN Distribute Point in Volume](https://developer.blender.org/D12636?id=48599) is not currently available ... its on the way :) ... Points on Face with Randomize would not work so well I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with particles. Just create meshes to the shapes you'd like and spawn sufficient particles all over.

Alternatively, using the same meshes, go into Geometry Nodes and use the **Distribute Points on Faces** node with the **Instance on Points** node.

See the screenshot below where I show a simple example with the default cube where I instance (in this case, itself) over points which were generated by the first node.

[image]

To instance another object besides the source object, add that object to your scene, then you need to add it into your node setup with an **Object Info** node, then use the Geometry output after selecting your new object.

Whether you go the GN or particle route, I'd advise using very simple Icospheres or Cubes for your case, as they're tiny points and don't require much geometry.

Play with the Density on the Distribute Points on Faces node until you get the desired result.

Edit: You can randomise the size of your instanced points using a **Random Value** node. By default, it gives you a single value with a grey output BUT if you change it from *Float* to *Vector*, it'll change into three values with a purple output. You can then plug this into your scale input on your **Instance on Points** node.

The rest is self-explanatory! :)

[image]

Comment: This is an excellent answer, thank you! Solving this through geometry nodes is very elegany and gives me just what I was hoping to get. Thumbs up!

Comment: Is there any way to randomize the size? I'm afraid I'm not so familiar with geometry nodes as I am with shading nodes...

Comment: @Ondrej yes! Let me edit my answer to include a screenshot of the node you need.

Comment: @Ondrej Done :)

Comment: Thank you very much :)